# moving out of jquery live

Tags: jquery

everyone is talking about moving out of live and using delegate. Here is my code in live.

```
$('a').live('click', function(){})
```

And here is converted code using delegate.

```
$('body').delegate('a', 'click', function(){})
```

This change seems to be working. However I do not have any tests and just want the validation from the community that this kind of change is okay and I can proceed.

Comment: That "click" in the second version should be a string constant.  Other than that, they're really identical.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out whether the source code really directly maps from one to the other, but jQuery source code is like a puzzle ...

Comment: well I can't close the question even though Pointy answered. :-(

Comment: can you provide some links where "everyone" is talking?

Answer (score 4):

Check the following link:

[Why You Should Never Use jQuery Live](http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live)

Besides, I think these two are equivalent:

```
$('body a').live('click', function(){})
$('body').delegate('a', 'click', function(){})
```

Comment: hey that article is spot on.  Thanks for posting it!